# Updating an object value in nested array React

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, object

I am trying to update a value within the state object of a React App. I am able to change the status string but I can't seem to figure out how to access the hp key for each fighter - I've tried different ways (I've written 2 in this example) without any success. What is the proper way of accessing the key of each fighter when you have an array with nested objects?

```
export default class App extends Component {
 state = {
  status: 'Fighters are Ready...',

   fighters: [
     {
       name: 'Fighter 1',
       hp: 150,
       image: ''
     },
     {
       name: 'Fighter 2',
       hp: 150,
       image: ''
     }
   ]
 }

 handleClick = (e) => {
  // console.log(e)
  if (e.target.name === 'Fighter 1') {
    this.setState({
       hp : this.state.fighters[1].hp - 10,
      status: e.target.name + ' is attacking ' + this.state.fighters[1].name
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      [Object.keys(this.state.fighters)[0].hp] : this.state.fighters[0].hp - 10,
      status: e.target.name + ' is attacking ' + this.state.fighters[0].name
    })
  }
  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sure to return an object of the same shape as the original state, while also avoiding mutation. Here [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) the current state into a new object, updating the `status` string as you were and then using a `map()` call to iterate over the `fighters` array and update the fighter that matches the `event.target`.

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  // console.log(e)
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    status: e.target.name + ' is attacking ' + this.state.fighters.find(f => f.name !== e.target.name)?.name,
    fighters: this.state.fighters.map(fighter =>
      fighter.name !== e.target.name
        ? ({ ...fighter, hp: fighter.hp - 10 })
        : fighter)
  })
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! I understand most, except for one thing - what does the ? mean after the find parenthesis? (If I remove/leave it still works) - I have never seen this before - Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's [optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which just saves it from throwing an error if the `find()` doesn't return an object. I threw it in for safety, but given your stable state it should work fine without it.